# R terra tif import colormap

Tags: r, terra

When importing a .tif raster with `terra::rast()`, also a colormap is imported. Is there any way to force the function to not import the colormap, or to set it to NULL to use the default plot color palette?

You can see the color table with:

```
terra::coltab()
```

Comment: Please, provide a reproducible example so that we can best help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols=3, nrows=2, vals=0:5)
coltb <- data.frame(t(col2rgb(rainbow(6, end=.9), alpha=TRUE)))
coltab(r) <- coltb
```

Normally, you should be able to do

```
coltab(r) <- NULL
```

But I see that the CRAN version has a bug  (now solved in version `1.4-5`). To work around it, you can do

```
coltab(r, 2) <- NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, Robert - I had hoped that you would see this. This confirmed my suspicion that there was a bug in the CRAN version.